# Boost disk access priority

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change I/O priority of a process or thread in Win7?](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7)

In order to speed up some process, which are accessing a lot of files, is it possible to give an higher disk priority to this processes ?

I'm working on Win 7.

***[Edit]*** I'm quite sure it's possible, because when running resource monitor, I see a `I/O priority` column in the `Disk activity` pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Windows 7 implements [only two I/O priorities, "normal" and "low"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301290/how-can-i-o-priority-of-a-process-be-increased/301333#301333)

"Low" is intended for things you're not waiting for, e.g. a file indexer running in the background.

Comment: :(... maybe I can ask my boss to invest in some ssd :)

Answer (score 0):

Try going into *Control Panel* then *System*.  Look under *Advanced System Settings* and select *Background Services* instead of *Programs*.

That or boost the process's priority through Task Manager.

Comment: ?? I don't want to boost the process CPU priority, but the disk priority ! And I don't understand your first statement (actually, I don't see how this can help to boost a specific process)

Comment: Disk IO "processes" are run as background processes.  Thus by switching to *Background Services* you can give all disk IO a boost.  For a process specific IO boost, you go through Task Manager.  That priority boost is **not just CPU**. When you boost a process, **everything** it does gets a boost.

Comment: Nope, there's no such things as "disk I/O processes". Background processes are the ones that don't have a window open. The "Programs" boost is based on the idea that a user is waiting for program with windows open, but doesn't care how fast invisible things happen.