# Dedicate IO priority to a process

Tags: windows, process, io, priority

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change I/O priority of a process or thread in Win7?](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7)

On Windows (7 in this case) it's possible to dedicate CPU priority to a process to make it go faster. In most cases IO is the bottleneck so I was wondering if there's a way to set IO priority at process level for IO intensive process (e.g. an installer or Visual Studio)?

Maybe this question makes no sense so tell me if that's the case...

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7 ;)

Comment: @Koen I closed your question as a duplicate of the linked question, if this question didn't solve your problem, edit your question to add more information about what didn't work, then flag it for moderator attention so it may be reopened